# Marketing cloud v2 api for saving contact data into data extension using api

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I had successfully posted a contact in SFMC using their v1 api and v1 login token but I want to do it using OAuth 2.0 token

```
https://xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:272C533C-193E-4FDF-BCCC-EE4A34B386C6/rowset

[
    {
        "keys": {
            "email": "someone@example.com",
            "subID": "12345"
        },
        "values": {
            "subID": "12345"
        }
    }
]
```

If I use OAuth 2.0 token in this api header then it gives 401 unauthorised., however same works fine with v1 token. I didn't find much documentation for the SMFC v2 API but only its Oauth api.

Comment: Check the permissions/scope that are passed in the call or set on the package. That could be causing the authorization issue.

Comment: I've provided all permission in the scope but still it gives this error.

Comment: I would check the permissions on the package, if the package does not allow the permissions, then I do not believe that including it in the scope of the API call will matter.  I have attempted the above call and it works perfectly with OAuth 2 token.

Comment: Have you verified that you have accounted for that the returned field is now 'access_token' in OAuth2 instead of 'accessToken'? perhaps you are returning a null value in your authorization?